# Community for Windows Customization and Mods

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where could I ask questions for modding or customizing Windows OS? I am about to ask something that refers to modifying a resource of a theme, but it doesn't need programming, or neither about my experience so I don't know if I can ask Stack Overflow or User Experience. Where should I ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like [Super User](http://superuser.com).

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

A search for "[customize windows theme](https://superuser.com/search?q=customize+windows+theme+is%3Aq)" returns 63 questions.